# #name? error in Excel (office professional plus 2010)

Tags: excel

I am trying to classify salaries for each employee by using this **IFS**

```
=IFS(F4<=3600,"Low salary",F4>=4120,"High salary",4120<=F4>=3640,"Medium salary")
```

[image]

In salary description when I apply the above formula it returns #NAME? error , When I double checked I found that the 2nd and 3rd conditions is returning true!
Can anyone assist me with this issue please?

Answer (score 2):

2010 does not have `IFS`. Use nested IF:

```
=IF(F4<=3600,"Low salary",IF(F4<=4120,"Medium salary","High salary"))
```

Comment: You are right :) My bad! i double checked and the function does not exist!